# !expected type-specifier before ‘=’ token

Tags: c++, types

I'm working on a Time Conversion problem in C++. It's been a while I've coded in C++ (usually use Python and MATLAB) and it threw up a bunch of errors (see attached)[image]

I'm certain these are elementary mistakes. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't use `new` as a variable name. The highlighting should already tell you that `new` is special.

Comment: [here's](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) the list of language reserved (and proposed) keywords

Comment: @GBlodgett that's the `operator new` function, not related to the `new` keyword

Comment: The " !cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strcat(char*, const char*)’ " still persists though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` is a keyword in C++. You can not call your variable `new` or any other keyword.  Choose a different name for that variable.

Comment: The " !cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strcat(char*, const char*)’ " still persists though.

Comment: @db18 that's a different error and your code displays multiple basic misunderstandings about the language. I would recommend trying to learn the language from a learning resource before coming back to this task